# Upload files using aws-sdk-android in Offline mode

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using [aws-sdk-android](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android) for uploading images from device to s3 bucket. I am using TransferUtility from the sdk to upload images.

```
 transferUtility.upload(Config.BUCKET_NAME, {File_Name},
                file);
```

My requirement is, I want to upload images in Offline mode. Basically, If the device is offline, SDK should cache the images and will start uploading whenever device comes online.

Does aws-sdk-android provide this feature or I have to handle this on my own?

Comment: In my knowledge Aws-sdk-android is not providing that functionality. You can programatically achieve this by checking whether network is available before submitting. If network not available then save path and other info in local Db and once network connection got you can get it done. You can also check for network connection by registering a broadcast listener.

Comment: You are correct, the SDK does not have this functionality.  We log this as a feature request.